# node.js express module not loading properly

Tags: node.js, load, express

```
Geos-Mac:hone georgiana$ npm list
/Users/georgiana/local/hone
├─┬ express@2.3.6 
│ ├── connect@1.4.1 
│ ├── mime@1.2.2 
│ └── qs@0.1.0 
├── gently@0.9.0 
└── mysql@0.9.1
```

However, a simple script that contains

```
var express = require( 'express' ).createServer();
```

gives

```
Error: Cannot find module 'express'
at Function._resolveFilename (module.js:322:11)
.........
```

when trying to use express.

Please note that

```
Geos-Mac:hone georgiana$ npm express -v
1.0.6
```

and

```
Geos-Mac:hone georgiana$ node -v
v0.5.0-pre
```

Any ideas?

Comment: What do you see if you type: require.paths in node shell?

Comment: `npm` installs modules locally. So your code needs to be near your `/.node_modules/` folder.

Comment: The require_paths output

`> require.paths
[ '/Users/georgiana/.node_modules', '/Users/georgiana/.node_libraries', '/Users/georgiana/local/hone/lib/node' ]`

`> Geos-Mac:node_modules georgiana$ pwd`
`/Users/georgiana/local/hone/node_modules`

`Geos-Mac:node_modules georgiana$ ls -lsa`
`total 0`
`0 drwxr-xr-x   5 georgiana  staff  170 May 21 13:55 .`
`0 drwxr-xr-x   7 georgiana  staff  238 May 21 13:54 ..`
`0 drwxr-xr-x   2 georgiana  staff   68 May 21 13:55 .bin`
`0 drwxr-xr-x   9 georgiana  staff  306 May 21 01:01 gently`
`0 drwxr-xr-x  13 georgiana  staff  442 May 21 01:01 mysql`

Comment: solved by installing the express module inside the application's folder; inspired by the manual

http://nodejs.org/docs/v0.4.1/api/modules.html#loading_from_node_modules_Folders

so, inside `/Users/georgiana/Sites/nodejs-play` I executed the `npm install express` command, which installed the module in `/Users/georgiana/Sites/nodejs-play/node_modules/express`

Answer (score 11, accepted):

solved by installing the express module inside the application's folder; inspired by the manual http://nodejs.org/docs/v0.4.1/api/modules.html#loading_from_node_modules_Folders

so, inside `/Users/georgiana/Sites/nodejs-play` I executed the `npm install express` command, which installed the module in `/Users/georgiana/Sites/nodejs-play/node_modules/express`